# Mobx statechange not detected

Tags: mobx, mobx-react, preact

I have a small simple setup. With mobx and preact.

```js
class AppStore {
    loadingobjects = true;

    constructor() {
        makeObservable(this, {
            loadingobjects: observable,
        });
        this.fetchCommonObjects();
    }

    fetchCommonObjects = () => {
        window
            .fetch(url)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((json) => {
                /* data processing */
                this.loadingobjects = false;
            });
    };
}

export const AppStoreContext = createContext();

function AppStoreProvider({ children }) {
    return (
        <AppStoreContext.Provider value={new AppStore()}>
            {children}
        </AppStoreContext.Provider>
    );
}

export default AppStoreProvider;

export default function useAppStore() {
    return useContext(AppStoreContext);
}

const List = observer(() => {
    const store = useAppStore();

    if (store.loadingobjects) {
        return <div class="ui active centered inline loader"></div>;
    } else {
        return (page content);
    }
});
```

problem is that `store.loadingobjects` Is always false. Seems like im doing something wrong but i cant put my finger on it...

What am i missing or doing wrong?

Edit addding my configs:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set NODE_ENV=dev && webpack serve --mode=development",
    "build": "set NODE_ENV=production && webpack -p",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.12",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.19.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.13.6",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "surge": "^0.19.0",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "mobx": "^6.7.0",
    "mobx-react": "^7.6.0",
    "preact": "^10.11.3"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const isProd = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    
    //input
    entry: ["@babel/polyfill",'./src'],

    resolve: {
        alias:{
            "react": "preact/compat",
            "react-dom": "preact/compat",
            "react/jsx-runtime": "preact/jsx-runtime"
        }
    },
    //output
    output: {
        path : path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename : 'bundle.js'
    },

    //transformations
    module: {
        rules : [
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                },
            }
        ]
    },
       
    //sourcemaps
    devtool: 'source-map',
    
    plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/index.html',
        favicon: "./src/favicon.ico"
    })],

    //server
    devServer: {
        compress: true,
        historyApiFallback: true
    }
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-react", ["@babel/preset-env", {"useBuiltIns": "usage",}]],
  "plugins": [
      ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"],
      [
          "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx",
          {
              "pragma": "h",
              "pragmaFrag": "Fragment"
          }
      ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you make a small reproduction on https://codesandbox.io/? I don't see any problems aside from that you create new store in your provider on every render, so if your providers ever rerenders the store will be recreated from scratch with empty data.

Comment: The issue does not reproduce on codesandbox. Added my config maybe my environement is messed up

Comment: @Danila Werid change happened. The state changes, but the component keeps rerendering. Its like in an endless render loop.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I started cutting the components into smaller pieces and then adding and removing them into the component hierarchy until i found the component causing the issue. It turned out that i had done `onClick={method()}` and this was changeing state causing the endless rerenders.